# How to show that $(1+\frac1x)^x$ is increasing on $[0,+\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to show that the function $f(x)=(1+\frac1x)^x$ on $[0,+\infty)$.

I have found that $f'(x)=f(x) \left[\ln\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)- \frac1{x+1}\right]$.

Since $f(x)$ is always positive, I only have to show that $$\ln\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)>\frac1{x+1}\text{ when }x>0.$$

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You don't need the word "always". Increasing on $(0,\infty)$ says it all.

Comment: This follows from the standard inequality $$\frac{x} {x+1}<\log(1+x)<x$$ for all $x>0 $ which is obtained by integrating the inequality  $$\frac{1}{x+1}<\frac{1}{1+t}<1$$ with respect to $t$ on interval $[0,x]$. Your desired result follows from the first part of this inequality if you replace $x$ by $1/x$.

Comment: The following more recent post is a multiduplicate: [Prove that $\ln\left( \frac{1+x}x\right) >\frac{1}{1+x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156979/prove-that-ln-left-frac1xx-right-frac11x)

Answer (score 9):

A different approach altogether:

If we start with Bernoulli's inequality, $(1+u)^r\gt1+ru$ for $u\ge0$ and $r\ge1$ (which is easy to prove by taking the derivative of $f(u)=(1+u)^r-1-ru$), we have, on letting $u=rx$,

$$\left(1+{1\over xr}\right)^r\ge1+r\cdot{1\over rx}=1+{1\over x}\implies\left(1+{1\over rx}\right)^{rx}=\left(\left(1+{1\over rx}\right)^r\right)^x\ge\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x\quad\text{if }r\ge1$$

hence if $y=rx\ge x$ then

$$\left(1+{1\over y}\right)^y\ge\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x$$

Comment: Very nice+1. Bernoulli inequality never ceases to amaze me!

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
&=\int_0^{1/x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\\
&\ge\int_0^{1/x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+1/x}\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{x+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How did you get from the first line to the second line?

Comment: @1123581321 When in doubt, draw a picture. i.e. sketch $1/(1+t)$ between $0$ and $1/x$. Now draw $1/(1+1/x)$ over the same values of $t$. The required argument should be completely obvious to you as soon as you do.

Comment: $1/x \ge t$ for $0 \le t \le 1/x$.

Comment: It is sort of amusing that I used this very inequality in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2445084).

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\frac{x+1}x>\frac1{x+1}$$
$$\iff-\ln\left(1-\frac1{x+1}\right)>\frac1{x+1}$$
For $x>0$, $0<\frac1{x+1}<1$, so substitute $y=\frac1{x+1}$:
$$\iff-\ln(1-y)>y$$
The Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-y)$ is always valid for $0<y<1$:
$$\iff y+\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^2}3+\dots>y$$
$$\iff\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^3}3+\dots>0$$
which is true since $y$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$g(x)
= \ln\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)-\frac1{x+1}
= \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac1{x+1}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g'(x)
&=\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x}+\frac1{(x+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{x(x+1)-(x+1)^2+x}{x(x+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{-1}{x(x+1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g(x)$ is decreasing.

But
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(1+1/x)
= 0
$
and
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac1{1+x}
= 0
$,
so that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)
= 0
$.

Therefore
$g(x)> 0$
for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem and there are already clever solutions (see [robjhon's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2445273/121671) solution above using integration)  and the comment by Paramanand Sing (using classical inequalities). Both strategies solve the problem under the assumption $x>0$, stated by the OP.

Here I just want to add that the statement is also valid for $x<-1$. The method follows the along the lines proposed by the OP, namely, to look at the sign of $f'(x)$. The whole method relies on a simple extension the inequalities mentioned by Paramanand Sing to all $x+1>0$.

> **Proposition:** If $t+1>0$, then $$\frac{t}{1+t}\leq \log(1+t)\leq t$$
> with equality iff $t=0$.

**Proof:** The right hand side follows immediately as $1+t\leq e^t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ with equality iff $t=0$. The left hand side can be obtained    from
$$\frac{1}{1+t}=1-\frac{t}{1+t}\leq \exp\big(-\frac{t}{1+t}\big)$$
by  taking logarithms on both sides of this inequality.

Using the computation of $f'(x)=f(x)\Big(\log\big(1+\tfrac{1}{x}\big)-\frac{1}{1+x}\Big)$ already provided by the OP, we obtain that for $x<-1$ or $x>0$, $1+\frac{1}{x}>0$ and so,
$$\log\big(1+\tfrac{1}{x}\big)-\frac{1}{1+x}=\log\big(1+\tfrac{1}{x}\big)-\frac{\tfrac1x}{1+\tfrac1x}>0$$

Putting things together, we obtain that $f$ is monotone increasing in $(-\infty,-1)$, and also monotone increasing in $(0,\infty)$.

---

**Comment:** The same technique works for showing that $g:x\mapsto \big(1+\frac{1}{x}\big)^{x+1}$ is monotone decreasing:
for all $x<-1$ or $x>0$
$$g'(x)=g(x)\Big( \log(1+\tfrac1x)-\tfrac{1}{x}\Big)<0$$
which follows by the proposition above.

All these yield following useful inequality
$$\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x<e<\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{x+1}$$
for all $x>0$ and
$$\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{x+1}<e<\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x$$
for all $x<-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x>0\implies\log (1+1/x)=\log (1+x)-\log x=$$ $$=\int_x^{x+1}(1/t)dt>\int_x^{x+1}(1/(x+1)dt=1/(x+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem 1.** For $x>0$, the function
$f_{\alpha}(x)=\bigl(1+\frac1x\bigr)^{x+\alpha}$ increases if and only if
$\alpha\le0$ and decreases if and only if $\alpha\ge\frac12$.

For $x<-1$, the function $f_{\alpha}(x)$ decreases if and only if $\alpha\ge1$
and increases if and only if $\alpha\le\frac{1}{2}$.

The necessary and sufficient conditions such that the sequence
$a_n=\bigl(1+\frac1n\bigr)^{n+\alpha}$ decreases or increases are
$\alpha\ge\frac12$ or $\alpha\le\frac{2\ln3-3\ln2}{2\ln2-\ln3}$ respectively.

**Proof.** Direct calculation gives
\begin{align*}
[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'&=\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1x\Bigr) -\frac{x+\alpha}{x(x+1)}&
\text{and}& & [\ln f_\alpha(x)]''&=\frac{(2\alpha-1)x+\alpha}{x^2(x+1)^2}.
\end{align*}

For $x>0$, it is easy to see that $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''>0$ and $[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'$ increases if and only if $\alpha\ge\frac12$. Since
$\lim_{x\to\infty}[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'=0$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, thus
$[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'<0$ for $\alpha\ge\frac12$, which means $f_\alpha'(x)<0$ and
$f_\alpha(x)$ decreases. This implies also that the sequence $a_n$ is
decreasing for $\alpha\ge\frac12$.

For $x>0$, it is clear that $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''<0$ and $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$
decreases if and only if $\alpha\le0$. Then $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'>0$,
$f_\alpha'(x)>0$ and $f_\alpha(x)$ increases for $\alpha\le0$. This implies
that the sequence $\bigl(1+\frac1n\bigr)^{n+\alpha}$ is increasing for
$\alpha\le0$.

For $x>0$, when $0<\alpha<\frac12$, the function $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''$ has a
unique zero point $x_0=\frac{\alpha}{1-2\alpha}>0$ which is a supremum point
of $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$, this supremum equals $[\ln
f_{\alpha}(x_0)]'=\ln\bigl(\frac1\alpha-1\bigr)+2(2\alpha-1)>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0^+}[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'=-\infty$ for $\alpha>0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'=0$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, it is yielded that the
functions $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$ and $f_\alpha'(x)$ have only one zero point
$x_1>0$, which is a unique infimum point of $f_\alpha(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$.
Consequently, the sufficient and necessary condition of the sequence $a_n$
being increasing is $f_\alpha(1)\le f_\alpha(2)$ which is equivalent to
$\alpha\le\frac{2\ln3-3\ln2}{2\ln2-\ln3}$.

For $x<-1$, the function $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''>0$ and $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$ is
increasing if and only if $\alpha\le\frac12$. From $\lim_{x\to-\infty}[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'=0$ it is deduced that $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'>0$ and
$f_\alpha'(x)>0$ in $(-\infty,-1)$. Consequently, the function $f_\alpha(x)$
is increasing in $(-\infty,-1)$ if $\alpha\le\frac12$.

For $x<-1$, the function $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''<0$ and $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$ is
decreasing if and only if $\alpha\ge1$. From $\lim_{x\to-\infty}[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'=0$ it follows that $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'<0$ and $f_\alpha'(x)<0$
in $(-\infty,-1)$. Accordingly, the function $f_\alpha(x)$ decreases in
$(-\infty,-1)$ if $\alpha\ge1$.

For $x<-1$ and $\frac12<\alpha<1$, the function $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]''$ has a
unique zero point $x_0=\frac{\alpha}{1-2\alpha}<-1$ which is a minimum point
of $[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'$. Since $\lim_{x\to(-1)^-}[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'=\infty$
and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}[\ln f_\alpha(x)]'=0$, then the functions $[\ln
f_\alpha(x)]'$ and $f_\alpha'(x)$ have only one zero point $x_1>0$, which is a
unique infimum point of $f_\alpha(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$. This completes the
proof of Theorem 1.

**Note.** The above theorem and its proof are extracted from the paper [3]. For more information on further developments, please refer to the papers [1,2,4] and closely related references therein.

**References**

1. C. Berg, E. Massa, and A. P. Peron, *A family of entire functions connecting the Bessel function $J_1$ and the Lambert $W$ function*, Constr. Approx. **53** (2021), no. 1, 121--154; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-020-09499-x.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *A property of logarithmically absolutely monotonic functions and the logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **72** (2010), no. 2, 21--30.
3. Feng Qi, Wei Li, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Generalizations of a theorem of I. Schur*, Applied Mathematics E-Notes **6** (2006), Article 29, 244--250.
4. Feng Qi and Aying Wan, *A closed-form expression of a remarkable sequence of polynomials originating from a family of entire functions connecting the Bessel and Lambert functions*, Sao Paulo Journal of Mathematical Sciences **16** (2022), no. 2, 1238--1248; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40863-021-00235-2.