# Show or disprove that $(1-k/n)^n < e^{-k} < (1-k/n)^{n-1}$ for all large enough n.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, summation

> Let $n\ge 2$ and $1\leq k<n$. Show or disprove that $(1-k/n)^n < e^{-k} < (1-k/n)^{n-1}$ for all large enough n.

The first inequality is true.

According to several of the proofs below, the second inequality actually doesn't hold for sufficiently large n.

Method 1)

Taking logarithms, and multiplying all inequalities by $-1$ we get $k > -(n-1)\ln (1-k/n).$ Using a Taylor series expansion (valid for $k < n$), we get $k < (n-1) \sum_{i=1}^\infty  \dfrac{(k/n)^i}i.$ The latter inequality holds since $k/(n-1) = (k/n)/(1-1/n) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty k(1/n)^i,$ and this is less than $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (k/n)^i/i$.

Method 2)

We have $k/n < \sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{(k/n)^i}i$ as $(k/n)^i>0$ for all $i\ge 0$.

We need to show that for large enough $x>k$, $k/(x-1) < -\ln (1-k/x)\Leftrightarrow k/(x-1) + \ln (1-k/x) > 0.$ Let $f(x) = k/(x-1) + \ln (1-k/x)$. Then $f'(x)=-k(\dfrac{1}{x^2-2k+1} - \dfrac{1}{x^2-xk}) = -k(x^2-xk - (x^2-2k+1))/((x^2-xk)(x^2-2k+1)),$ which exceeds zero for all $x>2.$ $f(x)$ actually tends to $0$ as $x\to \infty$ and $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to k^+$. So if $f$ is eventually strictly increasing, then since it tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty,$ $f$ should be less than zero for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: It's possible to prove both inequalities just by algebraic manipulation of $e^x \ge 1+x$. But I think this question has been gone over lots of times before on this website; see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121076/proving-1-1-nn1-gt-e).

Comment: The function $x\mapsto (1+1/x)^x$ is monotone increasing on $(-\infty,-1)$ (as well as on $(0,\infty)$ ans the function $x\mapsto(1+1/x)^{1+x}$ is monotone decreasing on $(-\infty,-1)$ (as well as in $(0,\infty)$). See for instance this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4139427/121671)

Comment: **TeX:** consider using displayed math (`$$...$$` instead of `$...$`) when appropriate; this also prevents the use of *ugly* `\dfrac`.

Comment: You do have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n=e^{-k}$$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{n-1}=\frac{e^{-k}}{1-\frac kn} $$

Comment: @OliverDíaz thanks for the observation. Okay so apparently calculators can be very annoying due to rounding issues. I've added an edit to my post that seems to strongly suggest that the claim isn't even true.

Comment: @MishaLavrov in this post I essentially provided three different ways to disprove the same claim and I thought each of these ways was incorrect. LOL.

Comment: @Piquito Your comment isn't correct, as there is n on the right hand side after taking limits.

Comment: @Andrew Zhang: You are right (i wanted to suggest that the denominator tends increasingly  to $1$ but i forgot to write it).