# How do we prove that : $n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{2n＋1}$

Tags: inequality

**Question**
How do we prove that :
$$n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{2n＋1}$$

**My attempt** $\text{prove by induction}$

in order to n=1 : correct becuase $3^2 \geq 2^3$

suppose $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \colon n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{2n＋1} $ and prove that :$(n+1)^{n+1}(n＋3)^{n＋2}\geq(n＋2)^{2n＋3}$

**I appreciate your interest**

Comment: What about trying induction ? Have you tried that ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it didn't work, I think I made a mistake, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: If you could edit a full answer I would be grateful to you

Comment: Don't you think that your attempt at using induction would be relevant to include as an attempt to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
{n^n (n+2)^{n+1} \over n^n (n+1)^{n+1}}
\geq
{(n+1)^{2n+1} \over n^n (n+1)^{n+1}},
$$
which is
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} \geq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}.
$$

---

Put
$$
a_m = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m.
$$
By the binomial theorem,
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_m
= {} & 1 + \frac{m}{m} + \frac{m(m-1)}{2!\, m^2} + \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)}{3!\, m^3} + \dots + \frac{m(m-1)(m-2) \cdots (m-(m-1))}{m!\, m^m} \\
= {} & 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right)
+ \frac{1}{3!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m} \right)
+ \dots
+ \frac{1}{m!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{m-1}{m} \right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which is not greater than
$$
1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right)
+ \frac{1}{3!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m+1} \right)
+ \dots
+ \frac{1}{m!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m+1} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{m-1}{m+1} \right),
$$
which is in turn not greater than

$$
1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right)
+ \frac{1}{3!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m+1} \right)
+ \dots
+ \frac{1}{m!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m+1} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{m-1}{m+1} \right)
+ \frac{1}{(m+1)!} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{2}{m+1} \right) \cdots \left( 1 - \frac{m-1}{m+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{m}{m+1} \right),
$$
which is just $a_{m+1}$.

Comment: nice answer .....     +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write
$$n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{2n＋1}$$
as
$$\bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg)^n\ge \bigg(\frac{n+1}{n＋2}\bigg)^{n＋1}$$
or
$$ \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n\le \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n＋1}\bigg)^{n＋1}. $$
Let
$$ f(x)=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^x. $$
Try to show [$f(x)$ is increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445230).

Comment: This is the second best method imo +1

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to

$$
\left( 1 + \frac 1 {n+1} \right)^{n+1} \ge \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n
$$

To prove this we can use the AM-GM inequality. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left( 1 + \frac 1 {n+1} \right)^{n+1} &= \left( \frac 1 n + \frac 1 n + \cdots + \frac 1 {n+1} \right)^{n+1} \\
&\ge (n+1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac 1 {n^n(n+1)} \\
&= \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is the best method imo +1

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log$ on each side to obtain
$$n\log n+(n+1)\log(n+2)\geq (2n+1)\log (n+1) \iff \frac{n\log n+(n+1)\log (n+2)}{n+(n+1)}\geq \log (n+1)$$
Then, by Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\log(n+1)=\log\left(\frac{(2n+1)(n+1)}{2n+1}\right)<\log \left(\frac{n\times n+(n+1)\times (n+2)}{n+(n+1)}\right)\leq \frac{n\log (n)+(n+1)\log(n+2)}{n+(n+1)}$$
We have used Jensen's inequality in the second inequality with $\phi(x)=\log x$.

Answer (score -1):

$$n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{2n＋1} = n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{n + n＋1} \iff n^n(n＋2)^{n＋1}\geq(n＋1)^{n＋1} \cdot (n＋1)^n 
\\\iff \left(\dfrac{n + 2}{n + 1}\right)^{n + 1} \ge \left(\dfrac{n + 1}{n}\right)^n 
\\\iff\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} \geq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}$$

If we show that $\displaystyle\left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{k}$ is increasing for $k > 0$, then we can prove $\displaystyle\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} \geq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}$.

It suffices that $\displaystyle\left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{k}$ is increasing $\iff\displaystyle k\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)$ is increasing. Let $\displaystyle f(k) = k\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)$.

$$f'(k) = \left(\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k}\right) - \dfrac{1}{k + 1}\right)\cdot\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k}\right)^k
\\\left(\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{k}\right) - \dfrac{1}{k + 1}\right)' = -\dfrac{1}{k\cdot(k + 1)^2} < 0
\\ \quad \\
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}{f'(k)} \to 0 \, , \space\text{but $f'(k)$ is  decreasing. Therefore $f'(k) > 0$ and we are done.}$$

Answer (score -1):

You made a main step of the proof!

After your work we need to prove $$\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n^2+2n}\geq\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}$$ or
$$\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}\geq\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n^2+2n},$$ which is true because
$$\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}>e>\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n^2+2n}=\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n^2+2n}.$$

Comment: I can't know the reason why someone downvoted this answer. At least he or she should give some reasons.